# How to write a .sdf file in Gazebo 3D simulator for a robot arm with 3 revolute joints?

Tags: simulation, robotics

Something similar to the CRS arm robot with 3 revolute joints. I am having trouble writing the sdf(Simulator Description Format) for the arm in Gazebo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you havent already read it, this is the sdf manual with description of each tag: http://gazebosim.org/sdf/1.5.html.

If you don't succeed in writing the sdf from scratch, maybe you can find a description file written in other format (eg urdf) and convert it with some tools.